# How to enable SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, wmi, privileges, shutdown

How do I enable `SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME` privilege in c++ ?
I have followed this from msdn document (https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/shutdown/how-to-shut-down-the-system). Using this doesn't help me to shutdown the system.
Is there is any other way to grant privileges to shutdown the system ?

Comment: What happens when you try to adjust the token to add the privilege? What does GetLastError() return? Are you running your program as administrator? It would be best to add your code and the results you're getting to the question directly.

Comment: When I try to run in non-admin , GetLastError() returns ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED - Not all privileges are asssigned to the caller.